# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1 when addSubview

Tags: ios, swift, subview

This error doesn't occur in the simulator but occurs on my phone. I have 5 different webViews, and I have a menu set up so that when one is selected, it is added as a subview and the other webViews are removed from the superview.

```
// MARK: - Hides all other webviews and shows selected
func hideOtherWebViews(selectedWebView: WKWebView!){
    self.navBarFixed = false
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if checkLoaded.currentWebView != self.selectedWeb{
            for webview in [self.facebookWeb, self.instagramWeb, self.googleplusWeb, self.twitterWeb, self.youtubeWeb, self.linkedinWeb]{
                // If it isn't the selected web view do this
                if webview != selectedWebView{
                            webview.removeFromSuperview()
                            println("web hidden")
                    // If it is the selected web view do this
                }else{
                    self.centerView.addSubview(webview)
                    webview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

                    //webview constraints
                    let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webview.superview, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                    let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webview.superview, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                    let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webview.superview, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                    let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webview, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: webview.superview, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

                    self.view.addConstraints([ top, right, left, bottom])

                    webview.scrollView.delegate = self
                    webview.navigationDelegate = self
                    webview.UIDelegate = self
                    webview.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
                    webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
                    self.whiteOverlay.alpha = 1
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                        self.whiteOverlay.alpha = 0
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    })
```

The error occurs on

```
self.centerView.addSubview(webview)
```

Comment: break in the debugger and see which object causes a bad access. self, centerview or web view (using 'po' command) -- I suspect centerview

Comment: since you dispatch async, could it be you deallocate anything too early

Comment: Can you show the properties of webView like `self.facebookWeb`,...?

Comment: @Daij-Djan yup, it's centerView that causes the bad access

Comment: @user3796209: I am facing same issue now.

Comment: @user3796209: How did you solve this issue?